# do multiple by a float type number using only shifting and adding

Tags: bit-shift, multiplication

How can I execute multiplication by 2.75 using only shifting and adding?
I know multiple by 2 is done by bit shifting 1<

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to multiply an int by a non-integer constant such as 2.75, then you can just break this down as:

```
y = x * 2 + x / 2 + x / 4; // y = 2x + 0.5x + 0.25x
```

which can be expressed using shifts and adds as:

```
y = (x << 1) + (x >> 1) + (x >> 2);
```

Comment: "do multiple by a float type number ...", `float x` and `x << 1` do not work together.

Comment: @chux: it depends on how you interpret the question, but I think OP wants to multiply an int by a floating point constant, and since they seem to expect shifting by 1 to multiply by 2 then I think this is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Fair enough, yet this method loses preciseness given the 2 roundings caused by the 2 separate right shifts.  Perhaps `(x<<1) + (x+x+x)>>2;` and incur one rounding/truncation.

Comment: @chux: sure - post that as an alternate answer (although note the possibility of overflow in the second term). I think it's just a homework question where they want the student to demonstrate an understanding that certain operations can be decomposed into shifts and adds, so accuracy and efficiency are not too important, but it's often good to go a little further than what is actually asked.

Answer (score 1):

To multiply by 2 simply left shift.

```
y = (x << 1) + ...;
```

To multiply by 0.75, multiply by 3 and divide by 4 (shift right 2).  Consider the value of `x==3`.  This results in `y==2`.  The math of `3*0.75` is `2.25`.  With `(x >> 1) + (x >> 2)`, the result would be `1`.

```
y = ... + (x+x+x >> 4);
```

To get a *rounded* value (assuming positive numbers), add 1/2 the divisor (which is 4 in this case) prior to dividing/right-shifting.

```
y = ... + (x+x+x + 2) >> 2;
```

All together:

```
// y = x*2.75
y = (x << 1) + ((x+x+x + 2) >> 2);
```

Comment: Very good - note however that you get overflow for values of `x > INT_MAX / 3`, whereas it ought to be possible in theory to generate correct values for `x < INT_MAX / 2.75`.

Comment: @PaulR True the above works for values up to `x_MAX/3` rather than `x_MAX/2.75`.  In either case, OP does not specifier overflow handling nor range requirements, so leave that for the next post.  As the shifting of negative integers creates issues, using `int` with`>>` and `<<` is not even a good starting point and so better to use `unsigned`.  That does not help the `x < x_MAX / 2.75` issue though other than no UB.